# key binding in LyX for c=entering matm mode and copying previous equation

Tags: math-mode, lyx, copy-paste, keyboard

Is there any specific way in LyX of binding a key to the following operation:

a) go into math mode
b) copy the immediately preceding piece of math, eg the last equation

at the current point of the cursor?

Thanks

Comment: in lyx you can use `ctrl+m` sequence for inline math mode, or `shift+ctrl+m` sequence for display math mode. Then you can use `ctrl+a` to select the whole equation inside your math environment

Answer (score 2):

In LyX you can use `ctrl+m` sequence or `shift+ctrl+m` sequence in order to enter into inline math-mode or display math-mode, respectively. Then you can use `ctrl+a` to select the whole equation inside your math environment.